# Handling itemclick event on tree panel Extjs 4

Tags: events, extjs, tree, onclick, extjs4

what I am trying to do is to get different reaction on a different tree LEAF click!

```
var myTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,   
    border: false,
    listeners: {
        itemclick: function(index) {            
            var record = store.getAt(index);
            alert(record);          
        }
    }
});
```

I tried with index, to get the index of leaf, nothing.
I can get a reaction on a node click, but how to get a specific reaction on every leaf?
I also tried giving ID to the leafs, no luck???

Maybe a simple example of

```
itemclick: function(Ext.view.View this, Ext.data.Model record, HTMLElement item, Number index, Ext.EventObject e) {  

}
```

Pleeasse help!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `itemclick` event listener's function param "index" does not point to your tree node's index. Like you mentioned in end of your question the syntax for the `itemclick` event is:

```
function(Ext.view.View this, Ext.data.Model record, HTMLElement item, Number index, Ext.EventObject e) {

}
```

Here is an example:

```
itemclick : function(view,rec,item,index,eventObj) {

    // You can access your node information using the record object
    // For example: record.get('id') or record.get('some-param')
    if(r.get('id')=='SP') {
        // I do my necessary logic here.. may be open a perticular window, grid etc..
    }

    if(r.get('id')=='CO') {
        // I do my necessary logic here.. may be open a perticular window, grid etc..
    }           
}
```

And here is an example of my tree node's data:

```
{ text: 'SP Reports', id: 'SP', leaf: true},
{ text: 'CO Reports', id: 'CO', leaf: true},
```

Comment: What about custom parameters? I can't get form record for example pareameter s even if it was send to store by json? How can I get this kid of parameters data?

Comment: I also need to know how to access custom parameters

Answer (score 6):

Itemclick handler already gives you everyting you need:

```
itemclick(view, record, item, index, e ) {
    var id = record.get('id');
    // do something depending on the record data.
    // console.log(record);
}
```

Comment: @ischenkodv best and cleanest approach in my eyes!

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do a generic treepanel's item click handler and to be able to get a custom field I added to the node object. This helped me out. I dunno if this is the standard and compatible ExtJs 4 way:

```
            (Some Panels Here),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'treepanel',
                listeners: {
                    itemclick: {

                        fn: function (view, record, item, index, e) {

                            console.log(record.raw.userData);
                        }
            (removed...)
```

Comment: What i was looking for, thanks!
I was needing it: record.raw
:)

Comment: I have `{ text: 'SP Reports', id: 'SP', leaf: true, custom: 'Hello'}` how to I access the custom property?