# Explain ExtJS 4 event handling

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, extjs4

I've recently started learning ExtJS, and have trouble understanding how to handle Events. I have no experience of any previous versions of ExtJS.

From reading various manuals, guides and documentation pages, I've figured out how to use it, but I'm not clear on how it works. I've found several tutorials for older versions of ExtJS, but I'm not sure how applicable they are in ExtJS 4.

I'm specifically looking on the "final word" on things like

- what arguments does an event handling function get passed? Is there a standard set of args that always get passed?
- how to define custom events for custom components we write? how can we fire these custom event?
- does the return value (true/false) affect how the event bubbles? If not, how can we control event bubbling from within, or outside of the event handler?
- is there a standard way to register event listeners? (I've come across two different ways til now, and I'm not sure why each method was used).

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094411/handling-itemclick-event-on-tree-panel-extjs-4) leads me to believe that an event handler can receive quite a few arguments. I've seen other tutorials where there are just two arguments to the handler. What changes?

Comment: Just noticed... off topic?

Comment: 88 Upvotes on the question, 155 upvotes on the first answer and the great and mighty Andrew decides this one is off topic.  Serious power trip going on!

Comment: I have voted to re-open this question as answers here are a gold mine. I have edited the question to better fit the Q and A style .

Comment: Please open this question again 'cause it is really helpful & genuine question. so blindly we can not close it.

Comment: This is a well worded question, and I see no reason to close it. Calling this off topic is ridiculous. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Let's start by describing DOM elements' event handling.

### DOM node event handling

First of all you wouldn't want to work with DOM node directly. Instead you probably would want to utilize [`Ext.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element) interface. For the purpose of assigning event handlers, [`Element.addListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-addListener) and [`Element.on`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-on) (these are equivalent) were created. So, for example, if we have html:

```
<div id="test_node"></div>
```

and we want add `click` event handler.
Let's retrieve `Element`:

```
var el = Ext.get('test_node');
```

Now let's check docs for [`click`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-event-click) event. It's handler may have three parameters:

> click( Ext.EventObject e, HTMLElement t, Object eOpts )

Knowing all this stuff we can assign handler:

```
//       event name      event handler
el.on(    'click'        , function(e, t, eOpts){
  // handling event here
});
```

### Widgets event handling

Widgets event handling is pretty much similar to DOM nodes event handling.

First of all, widgets event handling is realized by utilizing [`Ext.util.Observable`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) mixin. In order to handle events properly your widget must containg `Ext.util.Observable` as a mixin. All built-in widgets (like Panel, Form, Tree, Grid, ...) has `Ext.util.Observable` as a mixin by default.

For widgets there are two ways of assigning handlers. The first one - is to use [on](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-on) method (or `addListener`). Let's for example create `Button` widget and assign `click` event to it. First of all you should check event's docs for handler's arguments:

> click( Ext.button.Button this, Event e, Object eOpts )

Now let's use `on`:

```
var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
  text: 'Test button'
});
myButton.on('click', function(btn, e, eOpts) {
  // event handling here
  console.log(btn, e, eOpts);
});
```

The second way is to use widget's [listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-cfg-listeners) config:

```
var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
  text: 'Test button',
  listeners : {
    click: function(btn, e, eOpts) {
      // event handling here
      console.log(btn, e, eOpts);
    }
  }
});
```

Notice that `Button` widget is a special kind of widgets. Click event can be assigned to this widget by using [`handler`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler) config:

```
var myButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
  text: 'Test button',
  handler : function(btn, e, eOpts) {
    // event handling here
    console.log(btn, e, eOpts);
  }
});
```

### Custom events firing

First of all you need to register an event using [addEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addEvents) method:

```
myButton.addEvents('myspecialevent1', 'myspecialevent2', 'myspecialevent3', /* ... */);
```

Using the `addEvents` method is optional. As comments to this method say there is no need to use this method but it provides place for events documentation.

To fire your event use [fireEvent](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-fireEvent) method:

```
myButton.fireEvent('myspecialevent1', arg1, arg2, arg3, /* ... */);
```

`arg1, arg2, arg3, /* ... */` will be passed into handler. Now we can handle your event:

```
myButton.on('myspecialevent1', function(arg1, arg2, arg3, /* ... */) {
  // event handling here
  console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3, /* ... */);
});
```

It's worth mentioning that the best place for inserting [addEvents](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addEvents) method call is widget's `initComponent` method when you are defining new widget:

```
Ext.define('MyCustomButton', {
  extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
  // ... other configs,
  initComponent: function(){
    this.addEvents('myspecialevent1', 'myspecialevent2', 'myspecialevent3', /* ... */);
    // ...
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
var myButton = Ext.create('MyCustomButton', { /* configs */ });
```

### Preventing event bubbling

To prevent bubbling you can `return false` or use [`Ext.EventObject.preventDefault()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.EventObject-method-stopPropagation). In order to prevent browser's default action use [`Ext.EventObject.stopPropagation()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.EventObject-method-preventDefault).

For example let's assign click event handler to our button. And if not left button was clicked prevent default browser action:

```
myButton.on('click', function(btn, e){
  if (e.button !== 0)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: this, is greed, but is there any way to do the "addEvents" thing via some config? :)

Comment: @jrharshath, as far as I know, unfortunatly, there is no way of doing that via config.

Comment: how does one create these -'myspecialevent1', I see you've attached it and handled it but how do we create these?

Comment: @heyNow, event is created automaticaly when it is being fired

Comment: Brilliant answer! I'm new to ExtJs and was looking for a way to reference any element in the page and use event handlers on them, just like jQuery. You taught me to! Thanks!

Comment: little error in the section "Preventing event bubbling". stopPropagation is used to prevent the event bubling, and preventDefault is used to prevent the default behaviour/action.

Comment: Just for information, this.addEvents has been deprecated starting from EXT JS 5.0. So there is no need to add events now while firing custom events.

Answer (score 43):

## **Firing application wide events**

### How to make controllers talk to each other ...

In addition to the very great answer above I want to mention application wide events which can be very useful in an MVC setup to enable communication between controllers. (extjs4.1)

Lets say we have a controller Station (Sencha MVC examples) with a select box:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.controller.Station', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    ...

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'stationslist': {
                selectionchange: this.onStationSelect
            },
            ...
        });
    },

    ...

    onStationSelect: function(selModel, selection) {
        this.application.fireEvent('stationstart', selection[0]);
    },    
   ...
});
```

When the select box triggers a change event, the function `onStationSelect` is fired.

Within that function we see:

```
this.application.fireEvent('stationstart', selection[0]);
```

This creates and fires an application wide event that we can listen to from any other controller.

Thus in another controller we can now know when the station select box has been changed. This is done through listening to `this.application.on` as follows:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.controller.Song', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller', 
    ...
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'recentlyplayedscroller': {
                selectionchange: this.onSongSelect
            }
        });

        // Listen for an application wide event
        this.application.on({
            stationstart: this.onStationStart, 
                scope: this
        });
    },
    ....
    onStationStart: function(station) {
        console.info('I called to inform you that the Station controller select box just has been changed');
        console.info('Now what do you want to do next?');
    },
}
```

If the selectbox has been changed we now fire the function `onStationStart` in the controller `Song` also ...

**From the Sencha docs:**

*Application events are extremely useful for events that have many controllers. Instead of listening for the same view event in each of these controllers, only one controller listens for the view event and fires an application-wide event that the others can listen for. This also allows controllers to communicate with one another without knowing about or depending on each other’s existence.*

In my case: Clicking on a tree node to update data in a grid panel.

**Update 2016 thanks to @gm2008 from the comments below:**

In terms of firing application-wide custom events, there is a new method now after **ExtJS V5.1** is published, which is using `Ext.GlobalEvents`.

When you fire events, you can call: `Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('custom_event');`

When you register a handler of the event, you call: `Ext.GlobalEvents.on('custom_event', function(arguments){/* handler codes*/}, scope);`

This method is not limited to controllers. Any component can handle a custom event through putting the component object as the input parameter scope.

[Found in Sencha Docs: MVC Part 2](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/#!/guide/mvc_pt2-section-setting-up-listeners)

Comment: In terms of firing application-wide custom events, there is a new method now after ExtJS V5.1 is published, which is using Ext.GlobalEvents. When you fire event, you call `Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('custom_event');` When you register a handler of the event, you call `Ext.GlobalEvents.on('custom_event', function(arguments){/* handler codes*/}, scope};` Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qll). This method is not limited to controllers. Any component can handle a custom event through putting the component object as the input parameter `scope`. The question should be reopened.

Answer (score 15):

One more trick for controller event listeners.

You can use wildcards to watch for an event from any component:

```
this.control({
   '*':{ 
       myCustomEvent: this.doSomething
   }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Just wanted to add a couple of pence to the excellent answers above:
If you are working on pre Extjs 4.1, and don't have application wide events but need them, I've been using a very simple technique that might help: 
Create a simple object extending Observable, and define any app wide events you might need in it. You can then fire those events from anywhere in your app, including actual html dom element and listen to them from any component by relaying the required elements from that component.

```
Ext.define('Lib.MessageBus', {
    extend: 'Ext.util.Observable',

    constructor: function() {
        this.addEvents(
            /*
             * describe the event
             */
                  "eventname"

            );
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Then you can, from any other component:

```
 this.relayEvents(MesageBus, ['event1', 'event2'])
```

And fire them from any component or dom element:

```
 MessageBus.fireEvent('event1', somearg);

 <input type="button onclick="MessageBus.fireEvent('event2', 'somearg')">
```

Comment: Just for information, this.addEvents has been deprecated starting from EXT JS 5.0. So there is no need to add events now

Answer (score 11):

Just two more things I found helpful to know, even if they are not part of the question, really.

You can use the `relayEvents` method to tell a component to listen for certain events of another component and then fire them again as if they originate from the first component. The API docs give the example of a grid relaying the store `load` event. It is quite handy when writing custom components that encapsulate several sub-components.

The other way around, i.e. passing on events received by an encapsulating component `mycmp` to one of its sub-components `subcmp`, can be done like this

```
mycmp.on('show' function (mycmp, eOpts)
{
   mycmp.subcmp.fireEvent('show', mycmp.subcmp, eOpts);
});
```