# ExtJS: Scoping Confusion

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope, extjs4

Coming from a C++ background, I'm getting a little lost in Javascript/ExtJS function scoping - specifically when dealing with events.

Say I have a controller which listens in on many different events. These events could come from managed views, stores, application-level, ect. Currently, I'm doing something like this to ensure correct scoping:

```
init: function() {
    me.control({
        'someSelector': {
            someEvent: me.onSomeEvent.bind(me)
        },
        ...
    });
    me.application.on({
        applicationEvent: me.onApplicationEvent.bind(me)
    });
},
onSomeEvent: function() {...},
onApplicationEvent: function() {...},
```

Is this the correct way of going about things? I'm scared of using `this` inside `onSomeEvent()` and `onApplicationEvent` unless I know specifically what `this` is pointing to. Thoughts?

**edit**: here's some example code to show where `this` may be misleading.

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'uploadform *': {
            formUpload: this.onFormUpload
        }
    });
},

onFormUpload: function(form) {
    if(form.isValid()) {
        var formData = form.getValues();
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'upload',
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: {
                form: formData
            },
            success: this.onFormUploadSuccess // here, this is the controller
        });
    }
},

onFormUploadSuccess: function() {
    ...                                       // here, this isn't the controller
    this.application.fireEvent('dealAdded');  // this.application === undefined!!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although scoping can be confusing in JS don't be scared of it. 
Your controller maintains scope, so you don't need to uglify your code. It should look like this:

```
Ext.define('Pandora.controller.Station', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    ...    
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'stationslist': {
                selectionchange: this.onStationSelect
            },
            ...
        });
    },    
    ...    
    onStationSelect: function(selModel, selection) {
        this.application.fireEvent('stationstart', selection[0]);
    },    
   ...
});
```

An excellent event handling post is here: [Explain ExtJS 4 event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorials?rq=1) . 
Additionally when something is not looking right I resort to `console.log(this)` just to make sure I am looking at the correct scope.

**EDIT**
After seeing the example you provided the issue is not in the controller itself but in the Ajax request being async and executing in Window scope by default. ExtJS lets you set scope with `scope:this` config in the request, which will set the controller as scope for the success callback.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'upload',
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: {
                form: formData
            },
            success: this.onFormUploadSuccess // here, this is the controller
     ,scope:this
        });
```

Comment: In your example, for `onStationSelect`, you have no guarantee what `this` is pointing to. I had this exact problem, with `this.application` being `undefined`

Comment: `(this.onStationSelect)` resolves to a function, (in this case, `onStationSelect`), which is called with some arbitrary context

Comment: Is this equivalent to doing `success: this.onFormUploadSuccess.bind(this)` ?

Comment: follow-up: ... whats better? `bind` or `scope` ?

Comment: I find bind confusing. setting scope is very explicit, i am sure it does bind behind the scenes :)

Comment: Ya, tis what I was thinking. Anyways, I thank you for your help as usual :)