# Attaching event to Ext.component.Component in initComponent

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have the following code.

```
Ext.define(foo.MyComponent, {
   extend: 'Ext.Component',
   tpl: new XTemplte({'blah blah'}),
   data: {},
   initComponent: function(){
       this.callParent(arguments);
       this.on('click', function () {alert(1)});
   }
});
```

This is rendering properly. But the click event I am attaching inside initComponent is not getting registered. Am I missing something? I am using **ExtJS 4.2.1**

Comment: does your component fire click event? because Ext.Component does not.

Comment: How about mouseover and mouseout? Where can I get this detail?

Comment: Nope. Those are DOM events. The docs list all of the events a particular component supports: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Component

Comment: Event handling tutorial question has already been sufficiently answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorials/16346425