# Extjs4: beforeshow vs afterrender

Tags: events, extjs4

What is difference between beforeshow and afrerrender events of extjs components.

Also can I get reference to any document which describes the order in which extjs events fire (or which describes steps which happen before the component is displayed on screen) ?

Answer (score 4):

**beforeShow** listener is triggered only when you are toggling an extjs component using show()

**afterRender** is triggered for every extjs component after it has been rendered

Rendering happens before a show; it only makes sense that a component must already be rendered before it can be shown or hidden etc...

I don't know of any great documentation on extJS event occurrences/flow. This thread is about as good as I've seen: [Explain ExtJS 4 event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/extjs-4-event-handling-tutorials)