# AEM: locating selection in the drop down using keyboard keys

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have created a dropdown in a component which has a list of items in  alphabetical order. I want it to be selected or highlighted such that I can get to approximately location of an item if I type the first letter of it.
How can I do it in AEM6 ?

can I do it in jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create event handler functions in JavaScript for the dialog.

An example is http://abani-behera.blogspot.com/2013/10/attach-listeners-to-widgets-in-cq5-aem.html (CQ5 style ExtJS dialogs)

- S.O. dialog events: [Explain ExtJS 4 event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/explain-extjs-4-event-handling)
- AEM widget documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/widgets.html
- ExtJS documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html

Alternately, TouchUI example at https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-events.html  (skipping extra details because it sounds like you aren't using TouchUI dialogs at this time).

Comment: Which event can be used. Can i use jQuery for keyboard shortcut to location a selection like onkeydown or onkeypress ? Default events like highlight on onmouseover or select on onmouseclick should not get impacted.

Comment: @Ajax you haven't identified which dialog you are using: ExtJS vs TouchUI.  Because jQuery is assumed loaded in edit mode, you should be able to leverage you can use it.  But the dialog type drives which events are triggered or listened to.  Please refer to the AEM documentation for more details.

Comment: I am using extjs dialog.

Comment: S.O. helpful explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260134/explain-extjs-4-event-handling vs AEM widgets: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/components/widgets.html vs ExtJS documentation: https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/widgets-api/index.html