# EXT JS 4 - itemclick leaf event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, tree, extjs4

I'm new to sencha EXT JS and having a trouble to create a click event on my "Ext.tree.Panel". 
I have used "EXT JS 4 CMD ( 4.2.1 )" to generate a default app and changed the default view / Main.js file to include a following code: http://pastebin.com/PGT7dwmC

At this stage what I'm trying to achieve is to create a simple click event when leaf item is clicked and the message "Clicked" will be pop up.  The app compiles and opens correctly in web browser. However, no matter what I do, I cannot see any message on the console log or message pop-up when I click on the "tree.pannel" leaf item.

I have already spend days on this so any hints would be highly appreciated.

At the moment I'm trying to follow: [Handling itemclick event on tree panel Extjs 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094411/handling-itemclick-event-on-tree-panel-extjs-4), but no success yet.

Update:

New Code: http://pastebin.com/bYYUhzm7

Still not working. Any additional ideas?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `itemclick` config option in `listeners:{}` and move it one level up from `root` config to `TabPanel` config and it should work.

Comment: I have done that. This is a new code: http://pastebin.com/bYYUhzm7 . Still unable to see clicked message when clicked.